# How do I use JSON objects from Facebook with PHP?

Tags: php, json, facebook

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/event

I'm trying to grab some values from a Facebook JSON even object in PHP. Namely, title of event, location, and people attending. Using the Graph API.

```
<?php

$jsonurl = "https://graph.facebook.com/331218348435?access_token=2227470867|2.rtBZMkVIVgKGZ7Xr4px3Dw__.3600.1280822400-662817093|apY_UHK_2SKQFel3XxpKJ09GEo4.";
$json = file_get_contents($jsonurl,0,null,null);
$json_output = json_decode($json);
```

How can echo the values from  JSON output? I'm assuming it will be returned as an array.

Thank you!

Comment: You can see what's in the array or object with `print_r($json_output);`

Answer (score 8):

If you're using PHP, you can use the [PHP SDK](http://github.com/facebook/php-sdk) to query the API. This means you can make calls like:

```
$user = $facebook->api('/someusername', array('fields' => 'id,first name,last_name ...'));
```

However, with your example, you could do the following:

```
$url  = "https://graph.facebook.com/331218348435?access_token=2227470867|2.rtBZMkVIVgKGZ7Xr4px3Dw__.3600.1280822400-662817093|apY_UHK_2SKQFel3XxpKJ09GEo4.";
$user = json_decode(file_get_contents($jsonurl));

echo $user['first_name'];
```

As if you use `json_decode`, it should decode the result into a native PHP array (or in same cases, an object).

Answer (score 5):

Specify the second argument of `true` to `json_encode` to convert it to array and then you can print the output like this:

```
$json_output = json_decode($json, true);
echo '<pre>';
print_r($json_output);
echo '</pre>';
```

Now you can get specific item like this:

```
echo $json_output['title'];
```