# PHP: Facebook JSON objects

Tags: php, json, facebook

I'm trying to get the user location from Facebook.

In the Graph API › User page, says:

location : A JSON object containing name and id

I need the location name, and I cannot get it. So far I've done:

```
$loc = $facebook->api('/me', array('fields' => 'location'));
```

But I don't get it and don't know what else to do ..

Thanks a ton!

Comment: Does anything come back in $loc?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I use JSON objects from Facebook with PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3394745/how-do-i-use-json-objects-from-facebook-with-php) and [Facebook API and Json with PHP,how to?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4008525/facebook-api-and-json-with-php-how-to)

Comment: I have the permissions the api says, and the printing of $loc shows the id but not the name .. maybe it's not json but my php :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to request the "user_location" privilege.

If you're using the Login Button, add it to the perms parameter.

```
<fb:login-button perms="user_location"></fb:login-button>
```

If you're using the Javascript API, add it to the options parameter:

```
FB.login(function(response) {
    if (response.session) {
        // do stuff
    }
}, { perms:"user_location" });
```

You may also want to try this to see what data is available.

```
$response = $facebook->api('/me');
var_dump($response);
```

Comment: I had the perms already in the Login Button my problem is the location name. Printing /me, does not show the location.  My code is just printing the location id. Thanks a lot

Comment: With the proper permissions, I get this when I run your code snippet: `array ('location' => array('id' => 'location uid', 'name' => 'location name'), 'id' => 'user uid')`. The only thing I can think is that you don't have a location set in Facebook.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have right privileges, If not request them first.